# Can be this prime numbers' property useful?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

Today I've got a formula, which shows a way to write the result of multiplication between two generic integer $a$ and $b$.

$$a \cdot b=\sum_{i=0}^{\min[a,b]-1} k-2i$$
where $k=a+b-1$.
Showing it is true is easy.
That formula means that the result between the multiplication of two integer can be always written as the sum of certain *consecutive* all even or all odd integer (eg $5 \cdot 8= 12+10+8+6+4; \ 7 \cdot 5=11+9+7+5+3$). Moreover, since with multiplication you can get every interger exept for prime numbers, this leads to the fact that you can write in that way *all* the integer but not the prime. I was wondering if this property (I'd say non-property) of prime can be in some way usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Your interesting observation states in another way a well known fact. Obviously, the sum of more than one consecutive even numbers will be even, and hence not prime. It is widely known the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$. Hence, the sum of any consecutive sequence of odd numbers (say from the $(k+1)$th to the $n$th odd number) will be $n^2-k^2$ which equals $(n+k)(n-k)$. In order for the sum to equal a prime $p$, we require $p=(n+k)(n-k)$. This only allows the solution $p=n+k;\ 1=n-k$. In other words, the "consecutive series" would contain only one member, $p$ itself. In your summation, this corresponds to summing from the inferior limit $i=0$ to the superior limit $\min(p,1)-1=0$. That is, a summation with only one term in it, that term being $p+1-1-2(0)=p$. So you reach the same result by a different route.